# grid control with surrport for hierarchical data and frozen column?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, grid

I am trying to find out a way of showing hierarchical data ( 3/4 levels nested data) in grid ( in IE6+ ).

1. I want to show hierarchical data with vales for all columns at the parent and child nodes.
2. Also I want to freeze first two columns in the grid.
3. Be able to expand ( drill down ) the grid view by loading data on demand ( ajax)
4. looking at loading grid with about 800 to 1K rows.

I saw a few jquery grids where it does not support column freeze and other third party controls ( infragistics) generate so much of javascript that along with the first column IE also starts freezing.

Answer (score -1):

I use [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) [RadGrid](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/grid.aspx) - the best I've ever used. Take a look at some demos:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/declarativerelations/defaultcs.aspx
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/hierarchy/twotablesatlevel/defaultcs.aspx
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/performance/linq/defaultcs.aspx
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: disclaimer: I wanted to let you know that I work for Telerik!

Comment: Thanks for your response Pavel , the grid exaples look nice but do not fit the exact mix of functionality I want. I am still looking further into this if i find something.